# Webview doesn't render my HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

I have a HTML5 game that has js files, css, jquery and .ogg files. This game works fine on my website. Now I want to have an Application in Android that download the game's files, store them somewhere (ex. App Data) and then load it in a webview to play game in offline mode.
I also enabled the javascript for my webview:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

For testing my app, I put the game files in asset folder for now and load the index page of the game via:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

After installing and opening the app, I just get a black webview. Nothing is shown. I want to know how I can make it work without any changes in my game files or scripts? (because I want to have a web-service on my server that feed my application with the game files; the same files that is running on the website. Is it possible?!)

Thanks

Comment: a idea is to use http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Comment: @madalinivascu Almost it's true; but the problem is if I don't browse the pages I got no cached page. I want my application updates itself with the game files I have on the server.So if I don't browse any pages of the website, I still should be able to have the games on my device.

Comment: if your application isn't that complex use a SPA

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            Log.e("Error", description);
       }

   });

 String url = "POST_YOUR_URL_HERE";
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(url);
```

this may helps you.

Comment: I found something. My game needs a webserver to run. I should put the files on for example xampp to make it work locally. If I open the index.html file directly, I also get the black page in my laptop. Now what? How can I run it on my android app?